# Can anyone help identify this connection or a Victron Orion DC-DC Charger?

Tags: connector, identification

I need a replacement male connector for the female shown below. Can anyone identify the connector type?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have found the connector in question, it's a Phoenix Contact MSTB 2.5/2-5.08 PCB Terminal Block.

The part number should be 1757019.